Why does the last grouped dataframe in the series not load data to MySQL?
The first 3 grouped dataframes insert into MySQL perfectly. The 4th dataframe (or last in the series) appears to insert no data. E.g. in MySQL, running SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP_2024_05_18; returns 0 results, however for all other temp tables it shows the correct number of rows.
In this example I have 1 master dataframe that is split into 4 grouped dataframes based on a column in the dataframe called groupBy which contains a date string separated with underscores.



Grouped_Dataframe_Name
Row_Counts




2024_05_15
1612


2024_05_16
1332


2024_05_17
96


2024_05_18
83



The script then creates temporary tables in MySQL for each grouped dataframe and inserts the data from each df. All temporary tables are created perfectly, and all tables are populated perfectly except for the last table in the series which is created perfectly (all columns and types match the others) but no data in the MySQL table.
My Python script performs the below steps:

Splits a dataframe into grouped dataframes using a segmentation column called groupBy (contains string of date e.g. 2024_05_17).

FOR EACH GROUPED DATAFRAME
Creates a temporary table in MySQL with a dynamic title: temp_lookup_2024_05_17 where the date portion reflects the groupedBy value of the grouped dataframe.

FOR EACH GROUPED DATAFRAME
Inserts the rows from each grouped data frame into its corresponding table that was created.


# Group the DataFrame by 'group_column'
grouped = df.groupby('groupBy')

for group_name, group_data in grouped:      
    # Create temporary table for each dataframe in for statement
    create_temp_table_query = conn_prod.execute(text(f"""CREATE TABLE tmp_lookup_{group_name} as SELECT * FROM staging_lookup limit 0;"""))

    # Insert data from dataframe into temporary table
    group_data.to_sql(f"tmp_lookup_{group_name}", con=conn_prod, if_exists='replace', index=False)

I've tried:

Printing the master dataframe shows all data as expected

Printing the contents of each grouped dataframe is showing each group only contains its grouped data as expected
for group_name, group_data in grouped:
            print(group_name)
            print(group_data)
            print()


Counting the number of rows in each grouped dataframe shows the correct number of rows.

Counting the number of rows in each temporary table in the Python script and printing the result on screen shows the correct number of rows. This includes the final table.
# Insert data from dataframe into temporary table
group_data.to_sql(f"tmp_lookup_{group_name}", con=conn_prod, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Count rows inserted by select count(*) on each table
inserted_count = conn_prod.execute(text(f""" SELECT count(*) FROM tmp_lookup_{group_name}; """))
print('Rows inserted: ' + str(inserted_count.first()[0]))

As the TEMP_2024_05_18 table shows in Python that there are 83 rows in the table, I immediately jump to MySQL and do a count on the table and it shows 0 rows.


I've also tried switching from using engine.connect and the to_sql method to mysql.connector and cursor method. Both have the same result.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

maybe it needs some .commit() to send all data.

Answer (as suggested by @furas): Missing .commit()
After the to_sql command which copies the dataframe to the mysql table there should have been a commit command.
Why was this missed? This was not immediately obvious as the to_sql command is embedded in a for statement. This means that each execution of the for statement will effectively run a commit, however the last execution will not, resulting in the first X to_sql will commit and the results stored in the table, but the final to_sql will not commit hence the changes are lost.
Likewise, the print statement to count the number of records in the temp table is correct as those records are loaded into the table in mysql, but because there is no commit, the rows added are removed.
Fix: Add a commit line in the for loop after every sql statement.
Thanks furas!
Edit: Here is the completed code containing the commit line. Note that my mySQL connection engine is called 'connection' as referenced in the commit line.
# Group the DataFrame by 'group_column'
grouped = df.groupby('groupBy')

for group_name, group_data in grouped:      
    # Create temporary table for each dataframe in for statement
    create_temp_table_query = conn_prod.execute(text(f"""CREATE TABLE tmp_lookup_{group_name} as SELECT * FROM staging_lookup limit 0;"""))

    # Insert data from dataframe into temporary table
    group_data.to_sql(f"tmp_lookup_{group_name}", con=conn_prod, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    connection.commit()


@Capybara code added in the answer post thanks.
